# Converting VBA to javascript - interacting with external website

Tags: javascript, vba, outlook

I have written code in VBA to login to a website and display a given page based on criteria I enter via VBA input boxes.  Initially, I am taking a case number, enter it into an input box.  the code themn checks o to see if the website is already open - if it is, and I am already logged in, it goes to the case # page.  If I am not logged in, it them prompts me for my password to log me in, then redirects to the case # page.  I now have created a hph site that lists al lthe case #'s as links.  I would like to click the link and have the same process happen.  In this case I have already supplied the case # per the link, but need to still be able to cycle through the open IE windows to see if the program is open, if I am logged in, etc.  The big pieces I am missing are the equivilant to a password input box, and  how to cycle through the IE windows.  In VBA, I have created a custom form for the password; to cycle through the wIE windows I am using "For Each w In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows"

I can post the code I curently use if needed.

Thanks!

Pete

Comment: You are using outlook vba to do this?

Comment: I have code that is Outlook VBA, yes, but want to use a webpage powered by PHP and Javascript to achieve the same affect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand which part of your process needs logging in.

The website where you want to end ?

If so, isn't it already have some capability to display the login page which redirect afterward to the desired location ?) but you should note that unlike a VBA which is an actual process of your machine that can do many things (among which asking if some IE is launched and what are the loaded pages in it), a webpage containing javascript within - for example - IE is a program running in a sandbox, i.e. it cannot interact with most of your system. At some point you will need some plugin in your navigator that allow the sort of IE seeking you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Zzirconium; it sounds like what I have in VBA is the best I can get.  To answer your question - I am ultimately trying to make the process easier with less interaction to login to the program (username/password), and enter the case #.  Since I can save the username and password in a MySQL DB and have the case # be part of the link (or direct code), I would theoretically be able to click the link and be taken directly to the case.